# Calculations in MySQL using SELECT query?

Tags: mysql, select

what you see below is the stock table I made for my software. and I need to do many calculations using it. for example I need the sum of pidstk P000007 (qty) where type is 3,1 and type 2,4   then I want the answer of (type 3+1) - (type 2+4). how can I do this? sorry about my English. not really good at it.

```
+--------+------------+-----+------+-----------------+
| pidstk | dateup     | qty | type | refno           |
+--------+------------+-----+------+-----------------+
| P00007 | 2013-01-31 |  50 |    4 | 000000000000004 |
| P00007 | 2013-01-03 |  24 |    4 | 000000000000005 |
| P00007 | 2013-01-22 |  40 |    4 | 000000000000006 |
| P00007 | 2013-01-22 |  40 |    4 | 000000000000007 |
| P00007 | 2013-01-22 |  14 |    4 | ref             |
| P00007 | 2013-01-22 |   8 |    1 | ref             |
| P00007 | 2013-01-22 |   3 |    2 | ref             |
| P00007 | 2013-01-22 |   2 |    3 | ref             |
| P00007 | 2013-01-22 |   1 |    3 | ref             |
| P00007 | 2013-01-23 |  10 |    4 | 000000000000008 |
| P00007 | 2013-01-23 |   2 |    4 | 000000000000008 |
| P00007 | 2013-01-23 |  40 |    4 | 000000000000008 |
| P00007 | 2013-01-23 |  40 |    4 | 000000000000008 |
| P00007 | 2013-01-24 |   1 |    4 | 000000000000009 |
| P00007 | 2013-01-31 |  40 |    4 | 000000000000010 |
+--------+------------+-----+------+-----------------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this:

```
SELECT
  pidstk,
  sum(case when type in (1,4) then qty else 0 end)-
  sum(case when type in (2,3) then qty else 0 end)
FROM
  yourtable
GROUP BY
  pidstk
```

Comment: For the OP's reference, a list of aggregate functions and details about the `GROUP BY` clause can be found here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   SELECT
   pidstk,
  sum(case when type in (1,4) then qty else 0 end) as total_1_4 ,
  sum(case when type in (2,3) then qty else 0 end) as total_2_3,
  sum(case when type in (1,4) then qty else 0 end)- sum(case when type in (2,3) then qty else 0 end) as the_difference
  FROM stock
  GROUP BY pidstk
```

[**DEMO SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3d1f/4)